# Open file by name matching recursively from current folder

Tags: files, fuzzy-search

Our project has a folder structure which makes navigating files a bit of a hassle.

```
basefolder
--> libs
    --> libA
    --> libB
    ...
--> utils
    --> utilA
    ...
--> apps
    --> appTypeA
         ---> appA
         ---> appB
         ...
    --> appTypeB
    ...
--> external
    --> 
    ...
...
```

My colleague uses SublimeText and he has this search bar, which just treats all files as if they were in the current folder in combination with a fuzzy name matching which works great for our project.
Can I achive something similar with my emacs?

---

Edit: using projectile solves the question. One simple way to get this to work is by installing [prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude), which also includes helm and helm-projectile.

Comment: Also see my [Projectile guide](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-projectile.html) with many demos what it's capable of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `projectile`, probably the most popular Emacs package.

```
(require 'projectile)
(setq projectile-indexing-method 'alien)
(setq projectile-enable-caching t)
(projectile-global-mode)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then a prefix arg with `C-x C-f` etc. lets you match your input against absolute file names, which means that you can match directory components etc.  (You can also bind command `icicle-find-file-absolute` directly to a key, to avoid having to use a prefix arg.)

Input pattern matching can be fuzzy, using [various fuzzy-matching algorithms](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Fuzzy_Completion). You can switch matching mode on the fly.

More importantly, regardless of the kind of matching you use, you can match against multiple patterns, to narrow the choices progressively ([progressive completion](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Progressive_Completion)).

Completion can match file names (as usual) or [file contents](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs?action=edit;id=Icicles_-_File-Name_Input#icicle-find-file-of-content), or both.

[More info.](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_File-Name_Input)